# HTML-design problems with <iframe>?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, iframe

I have made a web page, it works perfectly with just any browser except on iOS browsers, a little annoying, strengthens my determination to never buy iOS stuff.

... I want to see a different Web page in an ... scroll-able in the top-down direction. It's very simple in standard HTML / CSS... but on a new iPhone, it becomes junk in the browser ?

Anyone who wants to tell the great, mysterious, unfathomable mystery how the HTML code should be ?

Comment: Please provide us with the code you have have at the moment, and what you have done to try to make it work. also, this is almostdifinitely not the fault of the browser, you need to make your website [responsive](http://w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)

Comment: You should post the code what you tried which give some problems.